# Conditional reverting of elements using jQuery callback + AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I need to revert an object based on an AJAX call that I make. However, I'm finding that the AJAX call does not finish before the function is finished executing.

I've tried various approaches but each one seems to come back to the same asynchronous problem - and I do not want to do a synchronous call.

How do I somehow wait until the AJAX call is complete and the answer is there before I move on to determine if I should revert or not?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$.ajax
({
    type: "GET",
    url: "quizData.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml)
    {
        var questionIdCount = 0;
        $(xml).find('question').each(function()
        {
            questionIdCount++;
            $("#question-container").append("<div class=\"question\" id=\"question-number-" + questionIdCount + "\">" + $(this).text() + "</div>");

            $("#question-number-" + questionIdCount).data('id', questionIdCount);

            $(".question").droppable(
            {

            }
            );

        });

        var answerIdCount = 0;
        $(xml).find('answer').each(function()
        {
            answerIdCount++;
            $("#answer-container").append("<div class=\"answer-id\" id=\"answer-number-" + answerIdCount + 
            "\">" + answerIdCount + "</div><div class=\"answer\">" + $(this).text() + "</div>");    

            $("#answer-number-" + answerIdCount).data('id', answerIdCount);

            $(".answer-id").draggable({
              revert: function(socketObj)
              {
                 if(!socketObj)
                 {
                     return true;
                 }
                 else
                 {
                    var questionId = $("#" + socketObj.attr('id')).data('id')
                    var answerId = $("#" + $(this).attr('id')).data('id');

                    return checkAnswer(questionId, answerId);
                 }


              },
              containment: "#containment-wrapper",
              scroll: true
            });


        }); 
    }
});
  $(document).ready(function() {

$.ajax
({
    type: "GET",
    url: "quizData.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml)
    {
        var questionIdCount = 0;
        $(xml).find('question').each(function()
        {
            questionIdCount++;
            $("#question-container").append("<div class=\"question\" id=\"question-number-" + questionIdCount + "\">" + $(this).text() + "</div>");

            $("#question-number-" + questionIdCount).data('id', questionIdCount);

            $(".question").droppable(
            {

            }
            );

        });

        var answerIdCount = 0;
        $(xml).find('answer').each(function()
        {
            answerIdCount++;
            $("#answer-container").append("<div class=\"answer-id\" id=\"answer-number-" + answerIdCount + 
            "\">" + answerIdCount + "</div><div class=\"answer\">" + $(this).text() + "</div>");    

            $("#answer-number-" + answerIdCount).data('id', answerIdCount);

            $(".answer-id").draggable({
              revert: function(socketObj)
              {
                 if(!socketObj)
                 {
                     return true;
                 }
                 else
                 {
                    var questionId = $("#" + socketObj.attr('id')).data('id')
                    var answerId = $("#" + $(this).attr('id')).data('id');

                    return checkAnswer(questionId, answerId);
                 }


              },
              containment: "#containment-wrapper",
              scroll: true
            });


        }); 
    }
});


function checkAnswer(questionId, answerId)
{
     var ajaxAnswer;
     $.ajax
     ({
        type: "POST",
        url: "getQuizAnswers.php",
        dataType: "xml",
        data: "questionId=" + questionId + "&answerId=" + answerId,
        success: function(xml)
        {
            console.log($(xml));
            $(xml).find("answer").each(function()
            {
                //alert($(this).text());
                if($(this).text() == "true")
                    ajaxAnswer = true;
                else
                    ajaxAnswer = false;

            });             
        }
      })

    return ajaxAnswer;  
}



});


});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spencer,

You should be able to control things with a `deferred` object, together with a reorganisation of the code to ensure that draggable is only set once the ajax within `checkAnswer` has responded.

I'm not 100% confident in every aspect of this but here goes :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function setDraggable(revert) {
        $(".answer-id").draggable({
            revert: revert
            containment: "#containment-wrapper",
        });
    }
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "quizData.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml) {
            var questionIdCount = 0;
            $(xml).find('question').each(function() {
                questionIdCount++;
                $("#question-container").append("<div class=\"question\" id=\"question-number-" + questionIdCount + "\">" + $(this).text() + "</div>");
                $("#question-number-" + questionIdCount).data('id', questionIdCount);
                $(".question").droppable({});
            });
            var answerIdCount = 0;
        $(xml).find('answer').each(function() {
            answerIdCount++;
            $("#answer-container").append("<div class=\"answer-id\" id=\"answer-number-" + answerIdCount + "\">" + answerIdCount + "</div><div class=\"answer\">" + $(this).text() + "</div>");
            $("#answer-number-" + answerIdCount).data('id', answerIdCount);
            if(socketObj) {
                var questionId = $("#" + socketObj.attr('id')).data('id')
                var answerId = $("#" + $(this).attr('id')).data('id');
                $.when(checkAnswer(questionId, answerId)).done(function() {
                    setDraggable(true);
                }).fail(function() {
                    setDraggable(false);
                });
            }
            else {
                setDraggable(true);
            }
            scroll: true
        });
        }
    });
    function checkAnswer(questionId, answerId) {
        var ajaxAnswer = true;//remains true unless an incorrect answer is received
        var def =  new $.Deferred();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "getQuizAnswers.php",
            dataType: "xml",
            data: {"questionId":questionId, "answerId":answerId},
            success: function(xml) {
                console.log($(xml));
                $(xml).find("answer").each(function() {
                    ajaxAnswer = ajaxAnswer && ($(this).text() == "true");
                });
                if(ajaxAnswer) 
                    def.resolve();//success
                else 
                    def.reject();//failure
            },
            error: function(){
                def.reject();//assume failure if ajax fails
            }
        });
        return def;//IMPORTANT!!
    }
});
```

This is moderately tricky and needs to be explained ...

Starting with `checkAnswer`, you will see that it now returns a [deferred object](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/), which becomes either resolved or rejected at some point in the near future (when "getQuizAnswers.php" responds).

Back in the `.find('answer').each(...)` loop, you will see that that the code has been turned inside-out. Now, instead of calling `checkAnswer()` within the draggabe, draggable is set in response to `checkAnswer` (more specifically, in response to checkAnswer's deferred being resolved or rejected).

As the draggable needs to be set under several conditions, the draggable code has been moved into a utility function, thus avoiding duplication. You may need to pass more parameters into this function to control its behaviour more specifically (in particular the jQuery selector).

This may need tweeking/debugging and there may be a simpler approach but this is what immediately comes to mind.

Answer (score 0):

You already have the call back there.

```
success: function(xml){
  }
```

is the call back function when ajax request is finished successfully.

so call `checkAnswer(questionId, answerId)` from somewhere inside it where you need it.

if you want the checkAnswer to be called once both the other ajax requests are finished, do something like:

```
$.when($.ajax("/page1.php"), $.ajax("/page2.php"))
  .then(checkAnswer(questionId, answerId));
```

[jQuery.when](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/)

Comment: The problem is in my revert: function(socketObj){ ... } block. Also, I'm not sure how to actually RETURN the correct value in the checkAnswer() function - because when I return ajaxAnswer to the calling function the AJAX call is not complete...I don't quite understand what to edit here.

Comment: You are trying to do asynchronous behaviour inside your synchronous logic, you anyway need ajaxAnswer to retun it, so only way is making it asynchronous. You should resort to an asynchronous logic like setting/resetting the revert propery of the scrolable inside success event of ajax.

Comment: There simply must be a way to implement this functionality, though, even if it requires some code reworking. I'll keep researching - unless anyone else has answer.